# Split string with substrings in Python

Tags: python, string

What's the best way to split a string containing substrings with quotes in Python?

`string = 'foo bar "some substring"'`

`result = ['foo', 'bar', 'some substring']`

My first thought was to iterate through the list and concatenate list elements containing quotes, but I assume, that there's a more beautiful way.

Comment: Theres a lot of ways to split the string, you can use ```split()``` method. for example - if the string look like that ```string = 'foo bar someString'``` you can split it in this way: ```result = string.split(" ")``` .

Comment: Can you elaborate on what the actual algorithm is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `split` from the built-in `shlex` module.

```
import shlex

texts = 'foo bar "some substring"'
result = shlex.split(texts)
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You're welcome. You can mark the answer as accepted if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

This was a lot harder than I thought it would be. But using `re`, I think the following gets you the result you want.  I know the regex is very ugly, but it seems to work.

```
import re

def quoted_split(s):
    def strip_quotes(s):
        if s and (s[0] == '"' or s[0] == "'") and s[0] == s[-1]:
            return s[1:-1]
        return s
    return [strip_quotes(p).replace('\\"', '"').replace("\\'", "'") \
            for p in re.findall(r'(?:[^"\s]*"(?:\\.|[^"])*"[^"\s]*)+|(?:[^\'\s]*\'(?:\\.|[^\'])*\'[^\'\s]*)+|[^\s]+', s)]
```